# Equivalent of the Dutch phrase "take it down a notch"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation

In Dutch, we have a saying 'Een toontje lager zingen' which basically means that the person should sing a bit lower, a.k.a "take it down a notch" or "put someone in his place".

*Sing a bit lower* is an almost literal translation from dutch. The phrase doesn't have to do anything with singing.

An example would go like this:

John is being pretty arrogant and offensive. He's stating things he doesn't know anything about, but pretends he does. He's talking down to other people, etc.

Then someone else comes in and burns him pretty good. Not by being mean, but by correcting him with actual true statements, where he was wrong.

Now this person put him in his place and made John 'een toontje lager laten zingen', a.k.a. sing a bit lower.

Is there an equivalent phrase or idiom to this in English? Or is it exactly "take it down a notch"?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, because "take it down a notch" and "put someone in his place" are two quite different things. Some answers gave you an alternative for the first phrase, some for the second.

Comment: The question title says "take *it* down a notch" however the body talks about taking a person down a notch, and these are two different usages. Taking a person down a notch corresponds to phrases like "take the wind out of his sales" however with the pronoun it, the phrase is more likely to mean reduce the volume, lower the intensity, or calm down. Clarification of the question title  would be good.

Comment: @barbecue That's "sails"--but otherwise, I agree completely.

Comment: That exists. Just change notch to peg or two.

Comment: Just use the phrase "take it down a notch".

Comment: @barbecue to clarify the title, I just meant any phrase that would describe how you would call it when someone has been taken down a notch. Any variation on this is welcome!

Comment: Echoing @barbecue—If it's not too abusive of the original Dutch, I would suggest editing your question and question title to use the phrase *take **someone** down a notch* rather than *take **it** down a notch*, to lessen confusion about your meaning.

Comment: I disagree. The title should be modified to match the question.

Comment: @1006a the OP can edit his post as he thinks fit, but IMO take someone down a notch can never mean "sing lower", whereas *"take it down a notch"* could be a passable translation. The title is now different from the example in the body *that* is slightly confusing.

Comment: Well this is my first time posting here, and my English isn't that great. I invite anyone to change the title as he sees fit. I don't exactly know what would be the correct phrase

Comment: The very important thing is not to change "notch" in the title or/and in the body because then the answers that refer to that term would become meaningless.

Comment: Agreed, I think I got it right now

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the context of *singing,* one can certainly ask someone to "take it down a notch" to reduce their prominence in an ensemble. It wouldn't be particularly polite, so how that request was delivered would be important.

In the case of deflating someone's arrogance, we might say that he had been **taken down a peg or two,** which is certainly similar to the Dutch expression.

The two expressions are kept separate in English, though. *Notch* would be for volume; *pegs* for position.

> **take someone down a peg or two**
>
> Make someone realize that they are less talented or important than they think are.
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/take_someone_down_a_peg_or_two)

Comment: In the words on my youth, "Dude, take a chill-pill yo!"

Comment: You would tell John to "take it down a notch" and, by doing so, you have taken him down a peg or two.

Comment: My favourite Scottish colloquialism is "put (a person's) gas at a peep" i.e. turn down the gas to a low setting so that a large burning flame is reduced to a tiny flame that just peeps from the burner.

Comment: "Notch" and "peg" actually are almost interchangeable, [according to Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take-down-a-notch). It's the _object_ of "take down" that makes all the difference: "Mary took _John_ down" and "John took _it_ down" both may have to do with John's arrogance, but the first is Mary's response to the arrogance and the second is [John's self-regulation](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Take%20it%20Down%20a%20Notch).

Comment: @DavidK I disagree: it's not appropriate to attribute singing too loud to arrogance -- it could just as well be not realising and a simple mistake.

Comment: The question is not about singing. The example given was, "John is being pretty arrogant and offensive." Singing is merely a metaphor.

Comment: The question was explicitly about singing when I answered it.

Comment: The timestamps tell a more complex story, but as the question was about a "saying," I would have regarded the singing as metaphorical even without the later clarification. This answer is still good (other than perhaps the distinction between notch and peg, which I think is prescriptive rather than descriptive); the question is the thing that is really mixed up. As long as OP wanted to know what someone else did _to_ John (and I suspect that _was_ the intended question), they may use "take someone down a peg or two."

Comment: the expressions are not separate in english. being taken down a notch or a peg is losing face either way.

Comment: @mendota Being **asked** to "take it down a notch" is not face-damaging in the same way as being *taken* down a notch. Neither is using "take **someone** down a notch" is not as idiomatic as "take him down a peg or two".

Comment: @BradleyUffner I prefer 'Hakuna yo tatas' :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach i don't quite follow. i'm only saying that *taken down a notch* is no different than *taken down a peg.* you can argue how common either one is all day or argue the difference when you change the object of the phrases, but i'm not.

Answer (score 23):

I would [**cut them down to size**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+down+to+size)

> To deflate the self-importance of (someone)

*idioms.thefreedictionary.com*

Cut down to size implies that the persons self importance is the thing that has been tackled, rather than necessarily what they are saying.

Comment: That's a good one.

Comment: _That’s_ the expression that was on the tip of my tongue but refused to brave passing through the gap in my teeth!

Comment: This is very commonly used.

Comment: If the person asking the question is looking for an american colloquialism that means what he described,  I think 'cut them down to size' does it.  As far as I'm concerned, I hear "take them down a notch" more than "take them down a peg or two" but I'd consider them synonymous.  Some how, taking them down a notch seems like a pretty gentle move but it seems like the phrase has some real bite to it still in Holland (sounds like it takes them down a number of notches!).  A notch might not bring much humility but cutting them down to size would.

Answer (score 21):

"Tone down" or "Tone it down" is an expression you may consider

Meaning of "tone something down" is the following as per thefreedictionary.com

"to cause something to have less of an impact on the senses of sight or sound; to lessen the impact of something prepared for public performance or consumption"

Example Usage:  "This is rather shocking. You had better tone it down a bit" or  "Tone down this paragraph"

Answer (score 14):

I've heard lots of phrases used in these contexts, several pretty similar to your Dutch saying. For a loud singer/talker, you can say:

> Bring it down a notch/peg/bit
> Turn the volume down (figuratively referring to a radio/speaker)
> Keep it down

If someone confronts an arrogant person and forces some humility into them, you can say they:

> Brought him down a notch/peg
> Knocked him off his high horse

Another use I can think of for phrases like this would be for someone with outrageous ideas:

> Get your head out of the clouds
> Bring it back down to Earth

And it's not as similar, but in the case of humbling an arrogant person, I'm also a fan of the phrase:

> Put him in his place

Comment: Upvoted for "put him in his place" which captures the sense of giving someone a reality check when they are being arrogant or overbearing.

Answer (score 7):

There is the BrE expression ["put a sock in it"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-a-sock-in-it), which really means *shut up* (or make less noise). It is commonly assumed to come from the early days of mechanical gramophones (record players), when the only viable means of reducing the volume was to stuff something, such as a sock, into the horn (loudspeaker). See: [Origin of the phrase 'put a sock in it.'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143719/origin-of-the-phrase-put-a-sock-in-it)

> **put a sock in it!** - informal humorous
>   ​
>   used to tell someone to be quiet or stop making so much noise:
>
> - Hey, put a sock in it, will you? I'm trying to work here.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 4):

*He made John take a step back and reconsider.*

> step back
>   v.
>   2. To withdraw from something, especially to consider it from a wider perspective:
>    ***Let's step back*** from the project for a moment and admire all that we have accomplished.
>   Rather than arguing about every detail, **they should step back** and determine what is really important.
>   - [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+step+back).

Comment: This is basically UD's definition of [Check yourself before you wreck yourself](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Check%20yourself%20before%20you%20wreck%20yourself)

Comment: @Mazura Cheers- I hadn't heard that phrase before but I see it has (as of today) 603 up-votes on UD ! I must be getting out of touch !!

Comment: @Mazura Or as I’ve frequently heard it said, in atrociously mangled pseudo-Shakespearean: “Check thyself before thy wreck thyself!” (\*shudder\*)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest the phrase "get a hold of yourself".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20hold%20of%20oneself)

> :  to get control of ones' thoughts and emotions and stop behaving in a foolish or uncontrolled way

This is often said to people who are speaking in a pompas manor. There are also variations, such as "get a grip on yourself".

Comment: In my experience this phrase is not usually applied to people who are being pompous, it's more likely used when someone is agitated, panic-stricken, or excessively ebullient.

Answer (score 1):

Since he's often wrong, John should **pump the brakes** on his constant criticism and corrections.

From the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pump%20the%20brakes):

> ### pump the brakes
>
> to tell someone to slow down when trying to jump conclusions about
>   someone or something; to slow your role; to caution another concerning
>   any particular matter

Comment: I am sure you could find a more reputable source than urban dictionary. It is not well-regarded here. Also, pictures which are non-essential to explaining your post are subject to removal.

Comment: This is not a common expression.

Comment: I've heard "put the brakes on" used to mean "stop and think about what you are planning to do" or "whoa, let's not be hasty" but I have never heard "pump the brakes" in the same context.

Answer (score 1):

For a thematic connection with the original: **[he changed his tune](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/change_one's_tune)**.

For example: *John was boasting about his chess skills, but when I told him my FIDE rating, he changed his tune.*

It's not an exact match, but it may fit your purpose.